# Sympy container objects that respond to simplify(...)

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to create a sympy container object with multiple sympy expressions inside it, representing the x, y and z observables of a qubit.

I started by creating a class that extends sympy.Basic. I was hoping that pushing x, y and z into the sympy args would result in an object that would respond to `simplify(qubit)` by returning an object with the x, y, and z args simplified. When that didn't work naturally, I redefined the `simplify(self, **kwargs)` method.

Is there a recommended way to get `simplify(qubit)` working rather than `qubit.simplify()`?

```
from sympy import Symbol, cos, sin, Basic
aa = Symbol('aa')
# simplifies to 1
expression_to_simplify = sin(aa)**2 + cos(aa)**2

class Qubit(Basic):
    def __new__(cls, qubitnumber, x, y, z):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, qubitnumber, x, y, z)
        obj.qubitnumber = qubitnumber
        return obj

    def simplify(self, **kwargs):
        from sympy.simplify import simplify
        return Qubit(
            self.args[0],
            simplify(self.args[1]),
            simplify(self.args[2]),
            simplify(self.args[3])
        )

qb = Qubit(1, expression_to_simplify, expression_to_simplify, expression_to_simplify)

print(qb.simplify())
from sympy.simplify import simplify
print(simplify(qb))
```

Gives output:

```
Qubit(1, 1, 1, 1)
Qubit(1, sin(aa)**2 + cos(aa)**2, sin(aa)**2 + cos(aa)**2, sin(aa)**2 + cos(aa)**2)
```

Comment: You should implement the `_eval_simplify` method rather than `simplify`.

Comment: Thanks. This was the hook into the process that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`simplify` is not written to provide support for simplifying the contents of containers, but you can make it so (or only do so for Qubit as follows):

```
>>> from sympy import simplify as _simplify
>>> def simplify(x, *y, **k):
...     if isinstance(x, Expr): return _simplify(x, *y, **k)
...     elif isinstance(x, Qubit): return Qubit(*[_simplify(i, *y, **k) for i in x.args])
...     raise NotImplementedError
```

This then gives `Qubit(1, 1, 1, 1)` for `simplify(qb)`. The trick is in using the original `simplify` as `_simplify` inside the new `simplify`.

Comment: I'd rather not consider writing another simplify function that wraps the existing sympy.simplify and adds special cases to it. "simplify is not written to provide support for simplifying the contents of containers": this is interesting and has made me reconsider whether I really want to integrate the Qubit type within sympy, and allow it to be used in expressions, or whether I want to have it sit outside.